# A word for something you keep coming back to to feel grounded, oriented

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

Is there a word for an object like this? Mantra is close, but is more like a ritual than a physical thing.

For example, a rosary could be a physical object that a Catholic uses to calm, center, orient themselves when stressed. A specific blanket helps my child do the same. A teddy bear serves that same purpose for another. I once read a story about a bulldog that wouldn't go anywhere without this specific log.

Is there a more general word or phrase for an object of this sort? "Comfort item" doesn't have the lyricism I'm looking for, but may be the only choice.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking for a physical object one goes to so they can feel more oriented in their mind, right? I was a bit thrown off when you mentioned *physical* thing when mantra (meditation) is more in the mind.

Comment: I think you're going to need to flesh out this question with what you mean by "grounded, oriented"; what sort of physical object you have in mind (what size, is it worn, is it visited); and under what circumstances one might have to use it.

Comment: _Touchstone, lodestone, anchor, lucky piece, fob,_ and others, depending.

Answer (score 2):

I use a **touchstone** myself.
[Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/touchstone):

> A standard or criterion by which something is judged or recognized: they tend to regard grammar as the touchstone of all language performance ... By the Second World War the toleration of COs had begun to be recognized as a touchstone of mature liberalism.

Comment: I think that has a different meaning, in that a touchstone actually has specific powers (as with the Sovereign Touchstone that turns everything it touches to gold).  A lucky penny or whatever has only psychological effects (not that it's less effective for that).

Comment: @TimLymington Yes, the technical sense is pretty specific, but you also read things like "It’s the corniest thing in the world to say this about someone, but she was a rock and she was my touchstone." http://www.express.co.uk/news/showbiz/456993/Martin-Kemp-praises-his-wife-Shirlie-for-getting-him-through-brain-tumour-ordeal where the meaning has blurred into almost exactly what is wanted here.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the term *[security blanket](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/security-blanket?showCookiePolicy=true)* (sometimes *comfort blanket*). According to *Collins American English Dictionary*

> - a small blanket or other soft cloth, as clutched or stroked by a child for the feeling of comfort and security it affords
> - anything that gives a person a sense of safety or freedom from anxiety

It also may be called a *comfort object* or *transitional object* as discussed in this *[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comfort_object)* article.

A related concept is *[comfort food](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/comfort-food?showCookiePolicy=true)*

> (informal) any food eaten not only for its pleasing taste but also for a sense of contentment, nostalgia, etc. that it provides [*Collins*]

Answer (score 0):

For me, my *phone* is the **pivot** of my daily life, and that, with other *pocket accessories* collectively form my **mainstay**.

I also like to call them **my props** which I feel assumes a blend of the metaphorically structural, and theatrical meanings.  Assuming I'm not in theater, then *my props* refer to my properties that prop my sense of self.

In technical writing, you might say *transitional object*.  If you put that in a song I like, you will have props from me, but no one will understand it.  Just to be clear, although I may give you props for your song, you cannot have *my props* no matter what, because they are **special**!  No one can have *those* but me.